# Angular 4 Modal dynamic data passing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

I have one common component for Modal and I want any data or message which comes from other components must go dynamically in this common modal component so that I don't have to rewrite modal code multiple times in the project.

I am new to Angular 4 and using service approach so please look into the code below and tell me how to correct it and what is the right approach to do it. Let any component below be any component and I want this modal to be popped up at the particular event so please help me in that also like how I can emit this modal on a particular event.

**modalcomponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ModalService } from '../../../_services/modal-loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: "./modal.component.html",
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  closeResult: string;


  constructor( private modalService: NgbModal,
              private ms:ModalService) {
    }

  ngOnInit() {
  }



  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
    console.log();
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }


  }


}
```

**modalcomponent.html**

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">{{ms.modalTitle}}</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>{{ms.modalBody}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>


<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>
```

**modalservice.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
//import { Http } from "@angular/http";


@Injectable()
export class ModalService {

    modalTitle:String='Default Title';
    modalBody:String='Default Body';
    openModal:boolean=true;

    createModal(modalTitle:String, modalBody:String, openModal:boolean ){
       this.modalTitle = modalTitle;
       this.openModal = openModal;
       this.openModal=openModal;
    }

}
```

**AnyComponent.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ModalService } from '../../../_services/modal-loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-any',
  templateUrl: "./any.component.html",
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AnyComponent implements OnInit {

  closeResult: string;


  constructor( private modalService: NgbModal,
              private ms:ModalService) {
    }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

Let AnyComponent below be any component and I want this modal to be popped up at the particular event so Please help me in that also like how I can emit this modal on a particular event.

Comment: can you please explain clearly ? emit to which component ? with component name

Comment: @Chandru I have automatic session expire functionality in my project so when session gets expire it must invoke this popup modal with message and on clicking ok of modal it must redirect me to login screen.

Comment: any updates here?